# Right row same, left row copy and repeat values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
index company 
ir     iris company
ir     ir company
in     india company
in     ind company
cy     cylindar company
cy     cyli company
ds     dsl company
ds     dsli company
```

I have above dataframe. If ir is the same, I have the company to copy the first instance at each index. For instance, all ir will have iris company, all in will india company, and all cy will have cylindar company. The return result should be:

```
ir     iris company
ir     iris company
in     india company
in     india company
cy     cylindar company
cy     cylindar company
ds     dsli company
ds     dsli company
```

Is there anyway to do it through pandas? If not, what could solve this problem?

Comment: df['New_company'] = df.groupby('index')['company'].transform('first')

Comment: Thank you, but this copy all the first instance. I mean first instance of each index

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do so with `pandas` using `groupby().transform('first')`:

```
df['company'] = df.groupby('index')['company'].transform('first')
```

Comment: Thank you, but this copy all the first instance. I mean first instance of each index

Comment: @KeFeng What do you mean **all the first instance**? it copies the first instance of each index to all row having the same index.